# Connecting to kafka from another namespace inside k8s

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, minikube, kcat

I have the following configuration for my kafka and zookeeper in my minikube:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-service
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  selector:
    app: kafka
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9092
      name: kafka-port
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9094
      name: kafka-port-out
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 2181
      name: kafka-zk
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka-deployment
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
      k8s-app: kube-dns
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
        k8s-app: kube-dns
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka-container
          image: bitnami/kafka:latest
          env:
          - name: 'ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER'
            value: 'yes'
          - name: 'KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT'
            value: 'zookeeper-service:2181'
          - name: 'KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS'
            value: 'PLAINTEXT://:9092'
          - name: 'KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS' # if I comment this and the next line it works only locally
            value: 'PLAINTEXT://kafka-service.kafka:9092'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
              name: kafka-port
            - containerPort: 9094
              name: kafka-port-out
            - containerPort: 5555
              name: kafka-port-jmx
            - containerPort: 2181
              name: kafka-zk
```

That is the configuration for my zookeeper:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-service
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  selector:
    app: zookeeper
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 2181
      name: zookeeper-port
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 2888
      name: zookeeper-peer
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3888
      name: leader-election
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-deployment
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper
      k8s-app: kube-dns
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper
        k8s-app: kube-dns
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: zookeeper-container
          image: bitnami/zookeeper:latest
          env:
            - name: 'ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN'
              value: 'yes'
            - name: 'ZOOKEEPER_ID'
              value: '1'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
              name: zookeeper-port
            - containerPort: 2888
              name: zookeeper-peer
            - containerPort: 3888
              name: leader-election
```

And I have another deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafkacat-deployment
#  namespace: debug # I was using it from another namespace, but it was not working so I've tried to use the same
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafkacat
      k8s-app: kube-dns
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafkacat
        k8s-app: kube-dns
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kafkacat-container
        image: edenhill/kafkacat:1.5.0
```

Then I try to telnet it, and it works.

```sh
telnet kafka-service.kafka 9092
Trying 10.101.87.127...
Connected to kafka-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Here is the nslookup

```sh
nslookup kafka-service.kafka
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   kafka-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.101.87.127
```

But when I try to reach it that is what I get:

```sh
kafkacat -b kafka-service.kafka:9092 -L
% ERROR: Failed to acquire metadata: Local: Timed out
```

So my guess it that the problem is in the Kafka configuration:
If I comment the env var `KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` it it works like that:

```sh
# kafkacat -b kafka-service.kafka:9092 -L
Metadata for all topics (from broker -1: kafka-service.kafka:9092/bootstrap):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1001 at kafka-deployment-858c5c7f98-tt7sr:9092
 2 topics:
  topic "my_topic" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1001, replicas: 1001, isrs: 1001
  topic "__consumer_offsets" with 50 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1001, replicas: 1001, isrs: 1001
```

If I try to produce a message:

```sh
kafkacat -b kafka-service.kafka:9092 -P -t my_topic
oi
% ERROR: Local: Host resolution failure: kafka-deployment-858c5c7f98-w2dm5:9092/1001: Failed to resolve 'kafka-deployment-858c5c7f98-w2dm5:9092': Temporary failure in name resolution (after 15382734ms in state INIT)
```

Then if I try to consume:

```sh
kafkacat -b kafka-service.kafka:9092 -C -t my_topic
% ERROR: Local: Host resolution failure: kafka-deployment-858c5c7f98-w2dm5:9092/1001: Failed to resolve 'kafka-deployment-858c5c7f98-w2dm5:9092': Temporary failure in name resolution (after 15406287ms in state INIT)
```

I have tried to configure the `KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092` but I still get timeout when I try to get the information with kafkacat.

That is why the advertised listener is the hostname which is not reachable from the local machine.
What can I do to fix the Kafka configuration in the cluster?

Comment: Where did you execute the telnet and consume commands? If you are trying to reach Kafka from your local machine, you'll have to set up a new svc resource for kafka-service using NodePort.

Comment: From another pod in the k8s cluster.

Comment: I am surprised why your kafkacat is responded of a host resolution failure to kafka-deployment-*. Can you try nslookup to kafka-service.kafka from the kafka-deployment pod and also from any other pod.

Comment: Sure, I have added to the question as well, but here is the nslookup
```sh
nslookup kafka-service.kafka
Server:  10.96.0.10
Address: 10.96.0.10#53

Name: kafka-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.101.87.127
```
The IP may be distinct cause I have deleted and created again the cluster.

Comment: Your telnet IP and nsookup IP differs. Is there any other kafka service in the same cluster?

Comment: The IP differs cause I have deleted and created again the cluster, it is running in my machine, I've updated the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I applied the exact same manifest as you provided except for adding a follow tail into /dev/null on kafka-deployment pod and was able to produce and consume topics.

I am running a k3s cluster in k3d:

```
└[~]> kubectl get nodes                                                    
NAME               STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
k3d-dev-server     Ready    master   31m   v1.17.3+k3s1
k3d-dev-worker-1   Ready    <none>   31m   v1.17.3+k3s1
```

kafka-deployment manifest:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafkacat-deployment
  #  namespace: debug # I was using it from another namespace, but it was not working so I've tried to use the same
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafkacat
      k8s-app: kube-dns
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafkacat
        k8s-app: kube-dns
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafkacat-container
          image: edenhill/kafkacat:1.5.0
          resources: {}
          command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - "exec tail -f /dev/null"
```

Terminal logs from kafka-deployment pod in Kafka namespace:

```
/ # kafkacat -b kafka-service.kafka:9092 -L
Metadata for all topics (from broker 1001: kafka-service.kafka:9092/1001):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1001 at kafka-service.kafka:9092 (controller)
 0 topics:
/ # kafkacat -b kafka-service.kafka:9092 -P -t my_topic
hi from kafkacat

/ # kafkacat -b kafka-service.kafka:9092 -C -t my_topic
hi from kafkacat
% Reached end of topic my_topic [0] at offset 1

/ # kafkacat -b kafka-service:9092 -L
Metadata for all topics (from broker -1: kafka-service:9092/bootstrap):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1001 at kafka-service.kafka:9092 (controller)
 1 topics:
  topic "my_topic" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1001, replicas: 1001, isrs: 1001
/ # kafkacat -b kafka-service:9092 -P -t my_topic
hi from kafka2

/ # kafkacat -b kafka-service:9092 -C -t my_topic
hi from kafkacat
hi from kafka2
% Reached end of topic my_topic [0] at offset 2
```

Terminal logs of kafka-deployment from debug namespace:

```
└[~]> kubectl exec -it kafkacat-deployment-76f9c9db6d-8fth4 -n debug -- ash
/ # kafkacat -b kafka-service.kafka:9092 -L
Metadata for all topics (from broker 1001: kafka-service.kafka:9092/1001):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1001 at kafka-service.kafka:9092 (controller)
 1 topics:
  topic "my_topic" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1001, replicas: 1001, isrs: 1001
/ # kafkacat -b kafka-service.kafka:9092 -P -t my_topic
hi from debug namespace

/ # kafkacat -b kafka-service.kafka:9092 -C -t my_topic
hi from kafkacat
hi from kafka2
hi from debug namespace
% Reached end of topic my_topic [0] at offset 3
```

I got it to work in minikube as well, after applying a workaround for a bug in minikube:

```
minikube ssh
sudo ip link set docker0 promisc on
```

Deleted the running kafka-deployment pod and it worked from both namespaces:

```
(⎈ |minikube:default)➜  ~ kubectl delete pod -n kafka kafka-deployment-5c4f64599f-kn9xt
pod "kafka-deployment-5c4f64599f-kn9xt" deleted
(⎈ |minikube:default)➜  ~ kubectl exec -n kafka -it kafkacat-deployment-b595d9ccd-4bht7 -- ash
/ # kafkacat -b kafka-service.kafka:9092 -L
Metadata for all topics (from broker 1003: kafka-service.kafka:9092/1003):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1003 at kafka-service.kafka:9092 (controller)
 0 topics:
/ # 
(⎈ |minikube:default)➜  ~ kubectl exec -n debug -it kafkacat-deployment-b595d9ccd-pgzv6 -- ash
/ # kafkacat -b kafka-service.kafka:9092 -L
Metadata for all topics (from broker 1003: kafka-service.kafka:9092/1003):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1003 at kafka-service.kafka:9092 (controller)
 0 topics:
/ #
```

Comment: The manifest you've edited is the one for kafkacat deployment, I've tried the same here but I still got no luck, maybe it is because I'm trying to use minikube instead of k3d.

Comment: I'm using k3s cluster in k3d now and it is working, if someone wants to install it, here is a step by step https://medium.com/@yannalbou/k3d-k3s-k8s-perfect-match-for-dev-and-testing-896c8953acc0

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**

This was tested using the confluent docker image, it works on my local minikube environment.

To access kafka from a different namespace you could use something like the following

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka-deployment
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
      k8s-app: kube-dns
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
        k8s-app: kube-dns
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka-container
          image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://${KAFKA_POD_IP}:9092
            - name: KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME
              value: PLAINTEXT
            - name: KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
              value: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
            - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              value: zookeeper-service:2181
          command: [ "sh","-c" ]
          args:
              - 'KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS="PLAINTEXT://${KAFKA_POD_IP}:9092" && /etc/confluent/docker/run'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
              name: kafka-port
            - containerPort: 9094
              name: kafka-port-out
            - containerPort: 5555
              name: kafka-port-jmx
            - containerPort: 2181
              name: kafka-zk
```

Please note though this is a work around.

The preferred solution is to create statefulsets for your kafka server. You will be able to reference the pod by the fqdn...

pod-name.stateful-setname.servicename

This will also give you a more stable environment if the server goes down, the stateful set will boot up again with the same name. Meaning your listeners will not fall over.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/